# Fortran assignment of values to elements of 2dim arrays - ICHAR

Tags: arrays, char, fortran, rank

I've got an array a(i,j) of rank two (matrix), each element of which is an ASCII character, e.g., `A` or `&` or `^` etc. When I want to translate the array elements into their integer codes, e.g., `b(i,j)=ichar('a(i,j)')` I get the following `Error: Argument of ICHAR at (1) must be of length one` which is strange because each a(i,j) is a single ASCII character. I can do the following (let a(1,2) be A): `y=a(1,2)`, `z=ichar('y')`, (y=A, z=121), but then I loose the array structure because when I try to print out `b(1,2)=z` (after compiling it) I get
`Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.`
`Backtrace for this error:`
`#0  0x7f301bac08da`
etc. (I have  `integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: b`)

How can I form `b(i,j)=ichar('a(i,j)')` and how can I address chosen elements of `b(i,j)` so as to be able to manipulate them in further calculations within the program?

I need the array structure of b(i,j) because a(i,j) has hundreds of columns and rows and because I want to correlate b(i,j) back with a(i,j) during further manipulation of b(i,j) elements. Switching to "lenght one" would be very clumsy even if possible.

Comment: Did not read the 2 examples I posted in your other question?  Those show you how to use `ichar`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
b(i,j)=ichar('a(i,j)')
```

you are passing the string `a(i,j)` to the function `ichar`, which expects one `character` only. If `a` is a matrix of characters, then you have to pass the value of one of its entries to `ichar`, as in

```
b(i,j)=ichar(a(i,j))
```

Comment: Of course, since `ichar` is *elemental* one could simply write `b = ichar(a)` if `a` and `b` have the same shape.

Comment: After a few years without fortran, it seems I don't remember much of it. Thank you for the comment :)

Comment: I mean, b(i,j)=ichar(a(i,j)) does not work for me (segmentation fault), but b=ichar(a) works flawlessly.

Comment: @Fvwm, if you post **in your question** a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we can give a look at it.

Comment: @Fvwm, as previously commented you'll need to provide more detail (perhaps in _another_ question) about the segmentation fault, but if `b=ichar(a)` works and `b(i,j)=ichar(a(i,j))` then a good guess would be that you haven't allocated `b` before the attempt with individual elements. With `b=.` `b` is allocated automatically as part of the assignment; with `b(i,j)=...` the array must be allocated before.